# Unable to get the file which have '.lock' extension inside PnP PowerShell script

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, document-library, pnp-powershell, file

I have this PnP PowerSell script to get all files which have `.lock` extension:-

```
$AllItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $Library -PageSize $BatchSize -Fields ID -ScriptBlock { Param($items) $global:counter += $items.Count; `
Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($global:Counter / ($Library.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity "Getting List Items of '$($_.Title)'" `
-Status "Processing Items $global:Counter to $($Library.ItemCount)";}  | Where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File" -and $_.FileLeafRef -like "*.lock" }
Write-Progress -Activity "Completed Retrieving Items from List $($Library.Title)" -Completed
         
#Process All Files from the Library
$global:Counter = 1
ForEach($Item in $AllItems)
```

But I will not get any file. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to fetch `.lock` extension file:

```
$LibraryName = "Documents"
$LibraryItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $LibraryName -PageSize 500 -Fields "FileLeafRef" | Where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File" -and $_["FileLeafRef"] -like "*.lock" } 

#Get File count
Write-Host "Total Number of Items Found:"$LibraryItems.count 

#Get each File name
ForEach($Item in $LibraryItems)
{
    Write-Host $Item.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"] 
}
```

Comment: worked well thanks a lot